# Getting in error while performing Nested STRUCT in C++

Tags: c++

I am solving a question of Nested structure in C++ but
I am getting an error in accessing the member function of struct Date i.e: void showdata()
First I have made a Data struct then in it I have added member function called void showdata which will show data of my another Struct Employee. However I can't access this member function in my main program.

ERROR :
Error   C2660   'Date::showdata': function does not take 0 arguments
so basically getting an error in the last line of code that is:
d.showdata()

Here's my code:

```
struct Date
{
    int year, month, date;

    void showdata(int empid, string name, double salary, int year, int month,int date)
    {
        cout << "\t\tEmployee's Data:\n";
        cout << "Employee ID --> " << empid << endl;
        cout << "Employee Name --> " << name << endl;
        cout << "Salary --> " << salary << endl;
        cout << "Joining Date -- >" << date << "-" << month << "-" << year << endl;

    }
};
struct Employee
{
    int empid;
    string name;
    double salary;
    Date joiningdate;
};

int main()

{
    //Q3
    Employee e;
    Date d;
    cout << "Enter Employee ID = ";
    cin >> e.empid;
    cout << "Enter Employee Name = ";
    cin >> e.name;
    cout << "Enter Salary = ";
    cin >> e.salary;
    cout << "Enter Employee joining year = ";
    cin >> e.joiningdate.year;
    cout << "Enter Employee joining month = ";
    cin >> e.joiningdate.month;
    cout << "Enter Employee joining date = ";
    cin >> e.joiningdate.date;
    d.showdata();
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error message.

Comment: Your `main` is not calling that member function `showdata(int, string, double, int, int, int)`.  It's calling a member function that does not exist, `showdata()`.

Comment: Hmm, I think the OP is attempting to call the right member function, but has some compiler errors for another reason.

Comment: Ok, I see you have included the compiler error. Why did you not supply the required parameters?

Comment: Why does `showdata()` take `year, month, date` arguments? Shouldn't it get the information from the member variables?

Comment: Why is the `showdata` method in the `Date` class rather than the `Employee` class?

Comment: You created `Date d` but you never assigned anything to its member variables.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to move the member function into the `Employee` class?

```cpp
struct Date
{
    int year, month, date;
};
struct Employee
{
    int empid;
    string name;
    double salary;
    Date joiningdate;
    void showdata()
    {
        cout << "\t\tEmployee's Data:\n";
        cout << "Employee ID --> " << empid << endl;
        cout << "Employee Name --> " << name << endl;
        cout << "Salary --> " << salary << endl;
        cout << "Joining Date -- >" << joiningdate.date << "-" << joiningdate.month << "-" << joiningdate.year << endl;
    }
};

int main()

{
    //Q3
    Employee e;
    cout << "Enter Employee ID = ";
    cin >> e.empid;
    cout << "Enter Employee Name = ";
    cin >> e.name;
    cout << "Enter Salary = ";
    cin >> e.salary;
    cout << "Enter Employee joining year = ";
    cin >> e.joiningdate.year;
    cout << "Enter Employee joining month = ";
    cin >> e.joiningdate.month;
    cout << "Enter Employee joining date = ";
    cin >> e.joiningdate.date;
    e.showdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined the `showdata` method inside the `Date` struct to take 6 arguments, yet when invoking the method in `main` you are supplying 0 arguments. To correctly invoke the `showdata` method you need to supply it with the correct set of parameters:

```
d.showdata(e.empid, e.name, e.salary, e.joiningdate.year, e.joiningdate.month, e.joiningdate.date);
```

Also be sure to check that the parameter types that you are passing in match the argument types that you defined the method to accept.